# Elasticsearch Java: Root type mapping not empty after parsing

Tags: java, elasticsearch, mapping

I'm trying to index a document in elasticsearch using the following mapping:

```
{"thread": {"properties":{"message":{"type": "nested", "properties": {"message_id": {"type":"string"}, "message_text":{"type":"string"}, "message_nick":{"type":"string"}}}}}}
```

Then using this to add the mapping in Java:

```
CreateIndexRequestBuilder indexRequest = client.admin().indices().prepareCreate(INDEX).addMapping("message", mapping);
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.MapperParsingException: Root type mapping not empty after parsing! Remaining fields:   [mappings : {thread={properties={message={properties={message_text={type=string}, message_nick={type=string}, message_id={type=string}}, type=nested}}}}]
```

Can anyone let me know how I'm getting this error?

Comment: do you want to store a whole thread as a single document in elasticsearch? It seems that you have a mapping for a "thread" type, but you are trying to create a mapping for the "message" type.

Comment: I'm trying to add mapping to the "message" type. Ultimately I wanted messages to be nested to I can search for occurrences of a keyword within the thread field but also find if any messages hold that keyword also. Can nested  documents help me do this?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the details for your exact mapping, but I had a similar problem and just realized that when you add mappings via the java API, you need to remove the json object right below the root.

For example, the mapping I tried to add was:

```
{"mappings":{"_default_":{"date_detection":false,"dynamic_templates":[{"dates":{"match":".*Date|date","match_pattern":"regex","mapping":{"type":"date"}}}]}}}
```

The above added fine using the REST API, but failed using the Java API with the same error you mentioned.

I removed the "mappings" json object and it fixed the issue.  Final mapping that worked was:

```
{"_default_":{"date_detection":false,"dynamic_templates":[{"dates":{"match":".*Date|date","match_pattern":"regex","mapping":{"type":"date"}}}]}}
```

Comment: One and a half Year old but you still made my day. Same belongs to the Javascript API - Thanks!